# session in login page in django

Tags: python, django, session, error-handling

i have a code , i have login form whenever the user fill login form than form will render to home page. but i want to print username in the home page who is logged in.

views.py :

this is login function , when user fill login form than it authenticate the values and render to the home page.

```
def userLogin(request,template=None,context=None):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = userLoginform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
#           authenticated_user = form.save()
#           login(request, authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/home/")
        else:
            template=u"registration/login.html"
            context= {"form": form}
            return render(request, template,context)
    else:
        form=userLoginform()
        template=u"registration/login.html"
        context= {"form": form}
    return render(request, template,context)
```

whenever i use this code , the user is logged in properly but the session value is not working , when i used {{ user.username }} in home page then it will not display session values.

Comment: It would be helpful to post the view code that is related to the homepage...however, try {{ request.user.username }} instead, unless you are passing the request.user as user in your context dictionary.

Comment: @JosephPaetz to be able to use `request.user.username` in the template he will need to add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to his settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suggested by Joseph you need to set the request.user to the context like :

```
    context= {"form": form, "user": request.user}
    return render(request, template,context)
```

thus in your template you will beable to access to `{{ user.username }}`

you can have a look at the complete doc about [how to use the auth system of django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/)

hope this could help

Comment: can you show us the template and the update of your view code to check ? 'cause it's like this we all give values to the template from the view